# Storing/passing configuration set in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, parameters

Need to store set of configurations for each region (DEV, QA etc.) in Jenkins. This configuration is required to be used by test cases which gets triggered after a successful build. For each region, there are multiple configurations required. Is there a mechanism in Jenkins that allow to fetch a set of configurations (may be a file) based on a name? For eg: DEV - mapped to a set of DEV configurations (URL, DB, EMAIL etc).

Comment: Do environment variables work? If so, you could source them all in a config file.

Comment: does it support key -> {set of key value properties} mapping? If DEV is passed as job parameter, it should pick all DEV config and start the job.
  eg:

DEV
url=http://devurl.com/
dburl=http://devdburl.com/
UAT
url=http://uaturl.com/
dburl=http://uatdburl.com/